# Codeigniter routes not working, possibly because of internationalization?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Working on codeigniter project.
Got stuck with routes. 
I want  to access **en/company/login** through **en/login**, so how do I define routes then?

Right now routes code looks like this:

```
// URI like '/en/about' -> use controller 'about'
$route['^(en|lv)/(.+)$'] = "$2";

// '/en', '/lv' URIs -> use default controller
$route['^(en|lv)$'] = $route['default_controller'];

$route['company/login'] = "login";
```

tried:

```
$route['^(en|lv)/company/login'] = "login";
```

Obviously, Im not getting something.
Can you help please?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is (i had the same) that this:

```
$route['^(en|lv)/(.+)$'] = "$2";
```

overrides your rule for:

```
$route['^(en|lv)/company/login'] = "login";
```

Try this:

```
$route['^(en|lv)\/(company)\/(.+)$'] = "login";
```

Maybe it should help you to override the first pattern

And if not, edit the first pattern to this:

```
$route['^(en|lv)\/(?!company).+$'] = "$2";
```

Comment: This line '$route['^(en|lv)\/(company)\/(.+)$'] = "login";', didnt help, and second line '$route['^(en|lv)\/(?!company).+$'] = "$2";' broke everything, now everythins is routed to default controller :/

Answer (score 0):

```
 $route["(en|fr|gr)/(:any)/login"] = "login/index/$1";
```

--

```
 public function index($company)
 {
       $language = strtolower($this->uri->rsegments[3]);

        if(!in_array($language, ['en', 'fr'])){
            // set a default language
            // if the route does not provide a valid one
            $language = 'en';
        }

        // Load the language file for the selected language
        // for example english, language/en/en_lang.php
        $this->lang->load($language, $language);

}
```

> Thank you for your answer, but it seems that I didnt explain that
>   /company/ is controller and /login/ is "company" function. Your
>   solution wont work for me. :/

```
// The $route should contain the uri,
// you seem to have them mixed up.  
// $route['uri'] = "controller/method"
$route['(en|lv)/login'] = 'company/login';
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems that I didnt explain that /company/ is controller and /login/ is "company" function. Your solution wont work for me. :/